# Get http proxy from HtmlUnit WebDriver from .pac proxy file

Tags: java, selenium, htmlunit, pac

I have configured an HtmlUnitWebdriver to use a .pac to configure the autoproxy. Is there once I am navigating with the webdriver to return the specific http proxy that it is using? Code for webdriver below.

```
    public WebDriver htmlDriver(){
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
        proxy.setProxyAutoconfigUrl("my_proxy_url.pac");
        DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.htmlUnitWithJs();
        caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
        HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(caps);
        LogManager.getLogManager().reset();
        driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        // String proxyUsed = driver.ReturnProxyHttp 
        return driver;
}
```

Comment: I don't undestand your question

Comment: @Arya Is it possible to determine which httpproxy the webDriver is using? The proxy is determined by the .pac autoconfigure.

Comment: I have never used .pac files, but how about loading it into a ArrayList<String> that way you can track which proxies are being used